# Outlook 2013 inline response and form region

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

In my Outlook 2013 add-in I want inline response form to use a form region with some additional controls.

When I open a message in a new window and click Reply customized form opens. But if I do it inline the standard outlook's Reply form opens.

Here is some code:

```
private void ReplyEventHandler(object Response, ref bool Cancel)
{
   ((MailItem)Response).MessageClass = "IPM.Note.MyCustomClass";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use your FormRegion in the inline response you have to do the following steps :

1. Create a new FormRegion.
2. Choose Adjoining as type
3. Change the properties your FormRegion. ->Display Conditions -> ShowInspectorCompose -> true.

This should work.