# How to show a CustomTaskPane in an InlineResponse only within the bounds of the responds like a Form Region

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-form-region

[image: CustomTaskPanel over whole explorer width]

The Screenshot shows an empty Form Region that is displayed the way I'd like to have my Custom Task Panel being displayed. The CTP, the panel at the bottom, is not supposed to take the whole explorer width.

```
this.pane = Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(mailForm, "TLS-Verfahren", ??);
```

This is the line to add the CustomTaskPane, question is what to put instead of '??'.
When I open an extra Inspetor window, its the inspector window.
But the issues is with the ActiveInlineResponse of the Explorer object. I don't have the window of only the (see picture) right side where the response is written.

I tried something like this:

```
var mailDocument = this.explorer.ActiveInlineResponseWordEditor as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document;
```

and then get the *ActiveWindow* of the *mailDocument*. But it's null (or actually throws a *ComException* when called)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have CTP at the bottom of the inline response only. It is either the right side of the explorer (next to the reading pane) or the bottom of the whole Explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Custom task panes can't be added to inline responses. Use the Outlook form regions instead. See [Create Outlook form regions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/creating-outlook-form-regions?view=vs-2022) and [Outlook 2013 inline response and form region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017242/outlook-2013-inline-response-and-form-region#:%7E:text=If%20you%20want%20to%20use%20your%20FormRegion%20in,your%20FormRegion.%20-%3EDisplay%20Conditions%20-%3E%20ShowInspectorCompose%20-%3E%20true.) for more information.

> This is the line to add the CustomTaskPane, question is what to put instead of '??'.

This is a custom task pane title string. The text that appears in the title bar of the new custom task pane.